# No Cloud templates on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-templates

As title suggests i cannot see any cloud functions in VS Mac. I have reinstalled many times, clean installs, redone dotnet core 3 and 5. I can see the functions plug in within vs mac.

I do have azure functions in VS Code for Mac

But i cannot see why i cannot get them in Visual Studio Mac - i cannot see how or where these are installed. I have all the other ones, just the cloud category is missing.

This is the very latest version of studio. Stable or Preview.

Any ideas?

thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Only the azure function template is available under cloud extensions; other templates can be found in other panes such as web and console, multi platform, iOS, Android, and so on. In Vistual studio mac, you may even create your own templates. More information can be found [HERE](https://medium.com/@jphenow/custom-file-templates-for-visual-studio-mac-f04269d49589).

While we're on the subject of Azure templates, you can learn more about them here [Azure - Visual Studio for Mac | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/azure-workload?view=vsmac-2019).

Comment: Thanks but the issue is I have no Cloud section in the templates and i cannot see why. That's the problem!

Comment: Can you try navigating to Visual studio > Extensions then search for azure functions and check if it has been installed or not

Comment: I have Azure Functions development installed, v 8.10.11... Is that the only extension? This is after a search for 'function'